# Collision between falling letters and blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I am making a game in which the collision between letters and boxes must be detected.

I came across width height comparison algorithm but how would I go about finding the letters's height and width properties?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>Game</title>
    </head>
    <style>
    #canvas{
        outline: 1px solid #000;
        background-color: #0099FF;

    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600">
</canvas>



<script>
var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF5050";
var xPos=0;
var yPos=500;
ctx.fillRect(xPos,yPos,70,70);
ctx.stroke();
function move(e){
    if(xPos+70<=canvas.width)
    {
        if(e.keyCode==39){
        xPos+=5;
        }
    }
    if(xPos>0)
    {
        if(e.keyCode==37){
        xPos-=5;
    }   }
    canvas.width=canvas.width;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF5050";
    ctx.fillRect(xPos,yPos,70,70);
    ctx.stroke();

}
document.onkeydown =move;
</script>


<script>
var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
function randomNumber(max) {

    var randomNum       = Math.random();
    var numExpanded     = randomNum * max;
    var numFloored      = Math.floor(numExpanded);

    return numFloored;
}

//create a function returning a random letter
function randomLetter() {

    var random0to25     = randomNumber(letters.length);
    var randomLetter    = letters.charAt(random0to25);

    return randomLetter;
}

//create a function creating a span containing a random letter and attaching it to body
function createLetter() {

    var span            = $("<span/>");
    span.css("position", "absolute");
    span.css("top", 0);
    randomCol=randomNumber(760);
    randomCol=randomCol+20;

       //concatenation
    span.css("left", randomCol+"px"); 
    span.text(randomLetter());

    span.appendTo("body");

    return span;
}

//explain how to animate an element
function makeLetterFall() {

    var letterElement = createLetter();
    letterElement.animate({"top":"95%"}, 5000);     //any ideas how not to use {} here?
}

//handle keyup, find a letter and remove it
/*function removeTypedLetter(pressedKey) {

    var typedLetter     = String.fromCharCode(pressedKey.keyCode);
    var letterElement  = $("span:contains("+typedLetter+")").first();

    letterElement.remove();
}*/

//$(document).on("keyup", removeTypedLetter);

//make a new letter every second
setInterval(makeLetterFall, 1000);

  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Why can't you use the width height of the wrapper span of the letter?

Comment: sorry but how do i use it?? @DeshanR

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to use canvas to draw both the falling letter and the blocks.

That way you can get the text's bounding box like this:

- set the text font with `context.font='36px verdana'`
- The approximate text height is the px font size + 2 (in this example `var textHeight=36+2;`)
- You can measure the text width using `var textWidth=context.measureText('A').width`
- Bounding box: x,y,textWidth,textHeight

To detect collisions you would check the text's bounding box against each rectangle's bounding box:

```
var textLeft=textX;
var textRight=textX+textWidth;
var textTop=textY;
var textBottom=textY+textHeight;

var rectLeft=rectX;
var rectRight=rectX+textWidth;
var rectTop=rectY;
var rectBottom=rectY+rectHeight;

// test if text & rect are colliding

return(!(
    textLeft>rectRight ||
    textRight<rectLeft ||
    textTop>rectBottom ||
    textBottom<rectTop
));
```

You can draw text on the canvas like this:

```
// context.fillText(text,x,y);

context.fillText('A',100,200);
```

To animate the text falling, in each new frame you would clear the canvas with `context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)` and then redraw the blocks & text in their new positions.